# Part of this code works, but rest doesn't

Tags: php, mysql

Why is it that only part of this works?  I'v added a comment to the working section:

```
session_start(); 
$_SESSION['views']=1;
$pageon="edited";
$button=" ";
$user=$_SESSION['username'];

$otoon = $_POST['otoon'];
$oserver = $_POST['oserver'];
$toonname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['toonname']);
$server = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['server']);
$guild = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['guild']);


echo $user . " " . $otoon . " " . $oserver . " " . $toonname . "<br />";

if (!empty($toonname)) {
$tql="UPDATE
        reguserstest AS rt
        INNER JOIN
            alt_toon AS att
        ON
            att.`toonname` = rt.`toonname`
        SET
            rt.`toonname` = CASE WHEN rt.`username`='$user' AND rt.`server`='$oserver' AND rt.`toonname`='$otoon' THEN '$toonname' 
                ELSE rt.`toonname` END ,

            att.`toonname` = CASE WHEN att.`username`='$user' AND att.`server`='$oserver' AND att.`toonname`='$otoon' THEN '$toonname' 
                ELSE att.`toonname` END
        WHERE
        ( rt.`username`='$user' AND rt.`server`='$oserver' AND rt.`toonname`='$otoon' )
        OR
        ( att.`username`='$user' AND att.`server`='$oserver' AND att.`toonname`='$otoon' )";
if (mysql_query($tql,$con))
        {
            echo "Toon name updated to: " . $toonname . "<br />";
            } else {
            echo "<h1>Error</h1>";
        }
}

//BEGINNING OF THE WORKING CODE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
if (!empty($server)) {
$sql="UPDATE
        reguserstest AS rt
        INNER JOIN
            alt_toon AS att
        ON
            att.`server` = rt.`server`
        SET
            rt.`server` = CASE WHEN rt.`username`='$user' AND rt.`server`='$oserver' AND rt.`toonname`='$otoon' THEN '$server' 
                ELSE rt.`server` END ,

            att.`server` = CASE WHEN att.`username`='$user' AND att.`server`='$oserver' AND att.`toonname`='$otoon' THEN '$server' 
                ELSE att.`server` END
        WHERE
        ( rt.`username`='$user' AND rt.`server`='$oserver' AND rt.`toonname`='$otoon' )
        OR
        ( att.`username`='$user' AND att.`server`='$oserver' AND att.`toonname`='$otoon' )";
if (mysql_query($sql,$con))
        {
            echo "Server updated to: " . $server . "<br />";
            } else {
            mysql_error();
        }
}
//THE WORKING CODE ENDS HERE ---- WHY??????

if (!empty($guild)) {
$gql="UPDATE
        reguserstest AS rt
        INNER JOIN
            alt_toon AS att
        ON
            att.`guild` = rt.`guild`
        SET
            rt.`guild` = CASE WHEN rt.`username`='$user' AND rt.`server`='$oserver' AND rt.`toonname`='$otoon' THEN '$guild' 
            ELSE rt.`guild` END ,

            att.`guild` = CASE WHEN att.`username`='$user' AND att.`server`='$oserver' AND att.`toonname`='$otoon' THEN '$guild' 
            ELSE att.`guild` END
        WHERE
        ( rt.`username`='$user' AND rt.`server`='$oserver' AND rt.`toonname`='$otoon' )
        OR
        ( att.`username`='$user' AND att.`server`='$oserver' AND att.`toonname`='$otoon' )";
if (mysql_query($gql,$con))
        {
            echo "Guild updated to: " . $guild . "<br />";
            } else {
            echo mysql_error();
        }
}
```

as I said,i can get the $server to update 100% of the time. but the $toonname and the $guild will not update. They both go to "Toon name/Guild updated to: WHATEVER" but they don't actually write onto the table.

Comment: *Obligatory:* The `mysql_*` functions will be [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: Please read about [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and update your code accordingly.

Comment: @Orangepill no $guild = "Anything"

Comment: @andrewsi my echo is thus:
UPDATE reguserstest AS rt INNER JOIN alt_toon AS att ON att.`guild` = rt.`guild` SET rt.`guild` = CASE WHEN rt.`username`='Leijae' AND rt.`server`='The Bastion' AND rt.`toonname`='Itzleijae' THEN 'oh yea' ELSE rt.`guild` END , att.`guild` = CASE WHEN att.`username`='Leijae' AND att.`server`='The Bastion' AND att.`toonname`='Itzleijae' THEN 'oh yea' ELSE att.`guild` END WHERE ( rt.`username`='Leijae' AND rt.`server`='The Bastion' AND rt.`toonname`='Itzleijae' ) OR ( att.`username`='Leijae' AND att.`server`='The Bastion' AND att.`toonname`='Itzleijae' )

Comment: why do you not escape otoon an oserver, too?

Comment: @JasonMcCreary I'll update when I get the stuff working, and I don't know when/if my host will update to 5.5 immediately. Also, still working on securing, but I want this to work.

Comment: @user2544291 - what happens when you run that directly in the database?

Comment: @steven i just added these, the other variables have been there a while. Once I get the code working, I secure it.

Comment: @andrewsi Affected rows: 0 (Query took 0.1456 sec)

Comment: @user2544291 - then there's something wrong with the WHERE clause you're generating, and it's not matching any rows.

Comment: @andrewsi i derped and ran it exactly as is, let me fill with the output

Comment: @andrewsi it seems like you're correct. After pasting in what was echo'd i still get "Affected rows: 0" but i don't know how, all of the data is there and correct.

Comment: @user2544291 - you're performing three updates. The first updates toonname; the second server; and the third guild. I think what's happening is that the first two queries are running, which mean that the WHERE for the third is no longer correct - server or toonname have been updated already. You should probably look to see if you can do your updates in one go, rather than performing each update separately.

Comment: @andrewsi that crossed my mind aswell, but as I mentioned only the 2nd update works correctly. If i leave the field for $toonname empty, it skips that update. if I leave the field for $server empty, $guild nor $toonname work correctly anyhow.

Comment: @user2544291 - could you edit your post to include the table definitions for reguserstest and alt_toon?

Comment: @andrewsi ok how do I do that do that?

Comment: @user2544291 - you need to go into the database and get the table description from there `DESCRIBE tablename` should list all the columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running separate update queries for each criteria; I think what's happening is that the earlier ones are interfering with the later ones. I'll suggest rationalizing them, and simplifying the SQL, too:

```
$userSQL = "UPDATE reguserstest SET ";
$altSQL = "UPDATE alt_toon SET ";

$toUpdate = array();

if (!empty($toonname)) {
    $toUpdate[] = "toonname='" . $toonname . "'";
}

if (!empty($server)) {
    $toUpdate[] = "server='" . $server . "'";
}

if (!empty($guild)) {
    $toUpdate[] = "guild='" . $guild . "'";
}

if (count($toUpdate)) {
    $userSQL .= implode(",", $toUpdate) . " WHERE `username`='$user' AND `server`='$oserver' AND `toonname`='$otoon'";
    $altSQL .= implode(",", $toUpdate) . " WHERE `username`='$user' AND `server`='$oserver' AND `toonname`='$otoon'";

    mysql_query($userSQL) or die ("User query failed: " . mysql_error());
    mysql_query($altSQL) or die ("Alt query failed: " . mysql_error());
}
```

I've not tested this, but you should get the idea.

It will update both tables seperately, with one query apiece. It checks to see if each field is set, and adds it to an array; if that array is empty, there's nothing to update. Otherwise, it runs two queries, and dies if either fails.

To re-iterate from the comments - you should look at moving to mysqli_ or PDO for security, as mysql_ functions are being deprecated; I'd definitely suggest testing this thoroughly to make sure I've not altered the logic anywhere.